# mcrypt_encrypt to openssl_encrypt ecb des

Tags: php, deprecated, mcrypt

i have to replace deprecated function mcrypt_encrypt using openssl_encrypt.
My old mcrypt function use 'des' cipher and 'ecb' mode.
I tried all cipher options (openssl_get_cipher_methods) and i cant find same result. Help please

```
$key = '04647132';
$message = hex2bin('046471324B3680');
$mcrypt = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt('des', $key, $message, 'ecb'));
foreach (openssl_get_cipher_methods(true) as $cipher) {
    $openSsl = base64_encode(@openssl_encrypt($message, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA));
    if ($openSsl == $mcrypt) {
        echo 'FOUND - ' . $cipher . ' = ' . $openSsl;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the different data padding - PKCS#5 for MCrypt and PKCS#7 for OpenSSL.

You can pre-pad `$message` yourself (either standard would work, but PKCS#7 is better) and use the `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` flag together with `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`. That also means you have to manually strip the padding after decryption - this is the case with all block cipher modes.

But this is the least of your problems ...

Nobody should be using using ECB, or DES today; you should move away from both as soon as possible. It's understandable if you maintain a legacy system, but you don't have to encrypt *new* data that way.
When you eventually move to another mode, don't ignore the IV requirement - the reason why ECB is bad is exactly because it doesn't utilize an IV.

Also, I know this is just sample code, but `$key` in your example isn't a proper key ... use `random_bytes()` to generate one.

All of this, and more issues that you don't even know about, could be resolved if you simply used a popular, well-vetted cryptography library - it would do all the work for you in one easy step.
Please do seriously consider this - even professional cryptographers prefer third-party libraries instead of writing their own code, and there's good reasons for that.