# How to use openssl to replace ect under encrypt encryption mode, the results of the encryption is not the same

Tags: php, php-openssl

```
$str = 'oJrPejuwDI0yQnz1PVPEpqoRHWQ8';
$key = base64_decode('TMCKn1LCSPeWo9m79qQ73IF/unFhdMxw1');
$Encr = new AesCryptUtil();
$en1 = $Encr::mcryptEncrypt($str,$key);
$en2 = $Encr::opensslEncrypt($str,$key);

$den1= $Encr::mcryptDecrypt($en1,$key);
$den2= $Encr::opensslDecrypt($en2,$key);
echo "加密前数据：".$str."\r\n";
echo "Encrypt加密后数据：".$en1."\r\n";
echo "Decrypt解密的数据：".$den1."\r\n";
echo "openssl加密后数据：".$en2."\r\n";
echo "openssl解密的数据：".$den2."\r\n";



class AesCryptUtil{
    private static $key = 'VE1DS24xTENTUGVXbzltNzlxUTczSUYvdW5GaGRNeHc=';
    /**
     * [encrypt description]
     * 使用mcrypt库进行加密
     * @param  [type] $input
     * @param  [type] $key
     * @return [type]
     */
    public static function mcryptEncrypt($input, $key) {
        $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $input = self::pkcs5Pad($input, $size);
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);//MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
        $data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        $data = base64_encode($data);
        return $data;
    }
    /**
     * [pkcs5Pad description]
     * @param  [type] $text
     * @param  [type] $blocksize
     * @return [type]
     */
    private static function pkcs5Pad($text, $blocksize) {
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
        return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }
    /**
     * [decrypt description]
     * 使用mcrypt库进行解密
     * @param  [type] $sStr
     * @param  [type] $sKey
     * @return [type]
     */
    public static function mcryptDecrypt($sStr, $sKey) {
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);//MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $sKey, base64_decode($sStr), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        $dec_s = strlen($decrypted);
        $padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s-1]);
        $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);
        return $decrypted;
    }
    /**
     * [opensslDecrypt description]
     * 使用openssl库进行加密
     * @param  [type] $sStr
     * @param  [type] $sKey
     * @return [type]
     */
    public static function opensslEncrypt($sStr, $sKey, $method = 'AES-128-ECB'){
        $str = openssl_encrypt($sStr,$method,$sKey);
        return $str;
    }
    /**
     * [opensslDecrypt description]
     * 使用openssl库进行解密
     * @param  [type] $sStr
     * @param  [type] $sKey
     * @return [type]
     */
    public static function opensslDecrypt($sStr, $sKey, $method = 'AES-128-ECB'){
        $str = openssl_decrypt($sStr,$method,$sKey);
        return $str;
    }
}
```

加密前数据：oJrPejuwDI0yQnz1PVPEpqoRHWQ8
Encrypt加密后数据：r0d668uEQfHeeNjfH6bsu8c/sMWeoD9GB8vLLuDQv3k=
Decrypt解密的数据：oJrPejuwDI0yQnz1PVPEpqoRHWQ8
openssl加密后数据：kcRSH49Gi5plcNrIqR53N6ZX5llo07V0EgllUaRnAKo=
openssl解密的数据：oJrPejuwDI0yQnz1PVPEpqoRHWQ8

After running the two methods of encryption are not the same result, but each can decrypt. Because the interface has been fixed, all now need to use openssl encrypted ciphertext and mcrypt encrypted the same, so only adjust openssl encryption

Comment: Its supposed to work that way. The variable $iv is used for that reason, it adds a randomness to each encryption.

Comment: Except ECB mode doesn't use an IV ... Haven't looked in depth at the code, but I'm guessing its the [padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45912756/mcrypt-encrypt-to-openssl-encrypt-ecb-des) that causes the difference.